# How to retrieve data with enum as string (EF Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

[Solved]How can i retrieve gender as a string like "gender": "Male" in my jsonResult, I'am using EntityFramework Core 2.2 with Asp.net core 2.2 project. I'am having trouble in enum, but in this example enum return string instead of int
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-types/enums)

My Model Employee

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
        public Genders Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

My Employee Configuration

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Employee", "HR");
        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(e => e.FirstName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(e => e.MiddleName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(e => e.LastName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(e => e.Birthdate)
            .HasColumnType("Date");
        builder.Property(e => e.Gender)
            .HasConversion(
                g => g.ToString(),
                g => (Genders)Enum.Parse(typeof(Genders), g));
```

}

My enum Gender

```
    public enum Genders
    {
        Unknown,
        Male,
        Female
    }
```

My Repository

```
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly DbContext Context;
        private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
            _entities = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ToListAsync()
        {
            return await _entities.ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

My API Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> Get()
        {
            return await _employees.ToListAsync();
        }
```

My Result

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "First Name 1",
    "middleName": "Middle Name 1",
    "lastName": "Last Name 1",
    "birthdate": "1991-10-04T00:00:00",
    "gender": 1 // I Want this result "gender": "Male"
  }
]
```

Solution: i add this into my startup.cs

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());

                });
```

Comment: You can add an attribute of `EnumMember(Value = "string")`. During the serializing of the object, it should convert the string to the object, or vice versa

Comment: using DataAnotation? what is the equivalent in fluentapi?

Comment: This comes from `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` and you apply it to each object inside the `Gender` enum. I believe this works with fluentapi.

Comment: I Try this but is not working [DataContract]
    public enum Genders
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "string")]
        Unknown,
        [EnumMember(Value = "string")]
        Male,
        [EnumMember(Value = "string")]
        Female
    }

Comment: Don't put "Solved" in your title.  Add the code that solved your problem as a proper answer and then tick the answer.  Remove the solution from your question.